# SharePoint create a site collection in a specific WFE server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I have a multi server farm with: 1 APP server + 2 WFEs + 1 Search server.

I want to create 2 site collections in a specific WFE, i.e. SiteCollection 1 in 1st WFE and SiteCollection 2 in 2nd WFE.

Is it possible?

Basically, I want to know that how can we know that which site collection gets created in which server and even if we know then can we control the site collection creation for each server and instruct SharePoint to create site collection in specific WFE server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not something what you can control. Because Site collections being created under the web application.

As you mentioned you have two WFE and you using the Load Balncer infront of those WFE which route the traffic on the base of Web Application URL not the site collection.

What you can control is in which content Database a site collection can go.

But one thing you can do,little ugly but  if you want do with two site collection only...then create two web application (Web App 1 & web App 2). Create the DBS records where WEB 1 point to 1st wfe and Web App 2 points to 2nd wfe. this way you know it. But this is not good solution and will not give you high availability.

Comment: Thanks for the answering my question and yes I agree that creating two Web Applications will not be a right approach.